# Global Solver Plotting

Tags: matlab, plot, iteration

I'm using the global solver to find the global minimum of my function.  I want to plot a graph where I can see the iterations of my objective function, starting and ending points, and found global minimum points.

Below is the code that I have so far, but I'm having trouble finding information on how to do this.

```
opts = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp','TolFun',1e-16,'TolX',1e-16,'MaxFunEvals',100000,... 'MaxIter',100000,'Diagnostics','on','Display','iter');

X0 = [1 1   1   0.1593  14.8 1.75 1 0.12    1   0.0027 1.86 0.5]; 
LB = [1 1   1   0.1593  14.8 1.75 0 0.12    0   0.0027 1.86 0.5]; 
UB = [1 1 1 1 90 pi/2 1 0.05 0.5 0.05 10 1];


fun=  (@(K)Efficiency_new_normal_all(K[sigmaef,AeffModef,PiTef,NredT,VGT,c,d,mred,etaTSef,...
repmat([gamma,R,Din,Dout,Dnut,Dwheel,BladeH,FPosition(i),RendMean,beta,a0,a1],[length(PiTef),1]),z2angle,z3geom]));

problem =createOptimProblem('fmincon','objective',fun,'lb',LB,'ub',UB,'x0',X0,'options',opts);

gs = GlobalSearch('PlotFcns',{@gsplotbestf,@gsplotfunccount});

[xfinal2,fval,exitflag,output,solutions] = run(gs, problem);
```

Comment: Read about the [`OutputFcn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html#f11022) and [`PlotFcns`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html#bqxk733) options.

Comment: I used the OuputFcn, but I'm getting the error as                      "GlobalSearch encountered failures in the user provided functions.

All 56 local solver runs failed in a user supplied function."